# Updating a Sharepoint List from Powershell

Tags: sharepoint, list, powershell, msdn

I can modify a new datarow in Powershell but it will not update the Sharepoint List on the site itself.

Here is a bit of my code

Here i fill my dataset with table info

```
$connString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://sharepoint/;LIST={6d552622-3333-4444-9999-234d32d32d3};'
$spConn = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connString)
$spConn.open()
$qry="select * from myList"
$cmd = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($qry,$spConn)
$da = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd)
$dataSet = new-object System.Data.DataSet
$sp = $dataSet.Tables.Add("Table")
$da.fill($sp)
```

Here i add a new datarow

```
 $row = $sp.NewRow()
 $sp.Rows.Add($row)
 $row["Title"] = "Foo"
```

And here i try to update the Sharepoint List

```
 $da.Update($sp)
```

It does not let me update, any help or guidence would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a new row which is an insert. Inserts are not supported by the OleDB provider against a SharePoint list. You can select or update the value of an existing row, but not create a new row.

Comment: What would be another way to add a new row then?

Comment: I need to do the same thing, anyone know how to add a row in sharepoint list from PowerShell? My script is not running on same system as SharePoint, so the .Net sharepoint assemblies are not available.

Comment: the above code will add a new Datarow, but as of now i cannot figure out a way to update it to the actually sharepoint list - i feel like there has to be a way

Comment: You're going to need to use CAML or the SharePoint cmdlet Get-SPWeb. Here's a link to Get-SPWeb example: http://secretsofsharepoint.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/06/22/adding-list-items-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Chad  I tried the cmdlet but it says it is not a recognizable  cmdlet??  Thanks

Comment: The cmdlet is not part of core Powershell and is only available on systems with SharePoint installed. You'll need to remote into SharePoint server. You can use Powershell remoting to run from your local machin.e The other option is to  use CAML.